# Find the N traversal of the Matrix / 2D array

Tags: javascript, matrix, multidimensional-array

given matrix / 2D array
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

we have to print

7 4 1 5 9 6 3 in javascript without using inbuilt functions

Comment: What exactly is the `N traversal` ?

Comment: N shape pattern
like if we have matrix
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

then we have to print 7 4 1 5 9 6 3

Comment: Your question states 74196**9**. I think you have a typo then.

Comment: sorry 741969 it was by mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var output= "";
var length = matrix.length;
// console.log(length)
for(var i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    output= output+ matrix[i][0] + " ";
}
// console.log(bag);
for(var j = 1; j < length; j++){
    output= output+ matrix[j][j] + " ";
}
// console.log(bag);
for(var k = length - 2; k >= 0; k--){
    output= output+ matrix[k][length - 1] + " ";
}
console.log(output);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint.

Assuming your matrix is presented as a 1-d array of integers:

```
m = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
```

which is logically assumed to be a "square" size  (1x1, 2x2, 3x3, 4x4, etc...)

So the above array is logically assumed to be:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

Let's use a helper function to help us obtain any that value at any given (x,y) position.  With (0,0), being the top left value of the matrix

```
let getVal = (m, col, row) => {
    let rowlen = Math.round(Math.sqrt(m.length));
    let index = row * rowlen + col;
    return m[index];
}
```

Hence, `getVal(m, 0, 0)` returns `1` for the top left corner and `getVal(m,2,2)` returns `9` for the value in the bottom right corner.

Now with that little helper function provided, do you think you can implement the three for loops for "going up from the bottom left", "diagonal from top left to bottom right", and "going up from the bottom right"?

Comment: this can be accept, but we dont have to use inbuilt functions thats the problem

Comment: what's an inbuilt function?  A function you wrote and you can't invoke `Math.sqrt` ?  I'm happy to show you an easy fix for that.  Or is matrix already passed as a 2-d array. You didn't indicate that in your question.